# Monitor settings always showup on secondary monitor. How to fix?

Tags: 11.10, multiple-monitors

I am using a secondary monitor connected to my laptop's VGA output.

However, many app popup dialogs, including Ubuntu's display settings show up on that secondary monitor. This is very annoying because I use it for display and I cannot easily see that monitor when working.

I have Unity menus on the laptop, which is supposed to be my primary. How can I enforce all new windows and monitor settings also show up on primary monitor?

I edited monitors.xml and added primary = yes to all displays which looked like laptop screens (for some reason I have several configurations there). Logged out and back in - same problem. See monitors.xml at http://pastebin.com/zJgstAbf

Comment: I'm not sure of a fix for this problem, but changing the RandR config in `monitors.xml` is unlikely to help.  In my experience, Compiz (the window manager Unity 3D is based on) doesn't do as good a job at placing new windows in multi-head environments as Metacity did.  Since Unity-2D is based on Metacity though, you could try picking it at login as a workaround.

Comment: I see, I did not realize I was using 3D since my graphics card is very basic on this laptop. Looks like I have it running in software mode. Will try to switch to 2D and see if it helps, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like switching to Unity 2D helped - now display settings show up on primary monitor.

Wow, this also made my desktop fast again, I did not realize how much slower Unity 3D was until this switch back! Thank you, James!